# Unpublished foreign applications considered prior art for EPO inventive step?

Tags: european, non-obviousness, epo

1. Is it true that third-party applications which are filed earlier but unpublished at the time of filing are not considered prior art for inventive step purposes in the EPO?  If so, this is a huge difference from the US, especially for fast-moving technologies.

From EPO examination guidelines:

> The state of the art also comprises the content of other European applications filed or validly claiming a priority date earlier than – but published under Art. 93 on or after – the date of filing or valid date of priority of the application being examined. **Such earlier applications are part of the state of the art only when considering novelty and not when considering inventive step**.

2. Assuming (1) is true, do the same rules apply in the EPO for non-EPO applications that are earlier-filed, not-yet-published?
3. (Bonus) Are the other major jurisdictions (JP, CN, KR) in line with the EPO or US on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. You already cited the correct source, a further one would be art. 54 (2), (3) EPC:

> (2)
>   The state of the art shall be held to comprise everything made available to the public by means of a written or oral description, by use, or in any other way, before the date of filing of the European patent application.
>
> (3)
>   Additionally, the content of European patent applications as filed, the dates of filing of which are prior to the date referred to in paragraph 2 and which were published on or after that date, shall be considered as comprised in the state of the art.

In combination with art 56 EPC which literally answers your question:

> An invention shall be considered as involving an inventive step if, having regard to the state of the art, it is not obvious to a person skilled in the art. If the state of the art also includes documents within the meaning of Article 54, paragraph 3, these documents shall not be considered in deciding whether there has been an inventive step.

2. Actually, only unpublished EP-Applications (or PCT-EP) are prior art before publishing for novelty, an unpublished US application is not even prior art for novelty. None is for inventive step.

By the way, in the US, prior US applications are prior art for both, *prior foreign applications for none*.

3. Afaik JP, CN are in line with the EPO on this, with respective national applications. The US is the outlier.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize this until now.  Though I will add that foreign priority can come into play, e.g. at least in the US, if an (even later-filed,) unpublished domestic application claims benefit of that foreign priority.

Comment: DonQuiKong, regarding your answer to p2 do you have reference to EPC articles/rules, EPO guidelines or EPO case law?

Comment: @MikkPutk it follows from the cited art. 54(2) and 56 or what do you mean?

Comment: Also, based on this alone, this would allow two different patentees/potential infringees to have patents on obvious variants of the same matter, and obviousness-type double-patenting rejections would seem to not to exist in the EPO (unlike the US).

Comment: @user132162 yes.

Comment: This source (http://aboutiplaw.com/noteworthy/patent-noteworthy/1425/) would  seem to disagree with your US note on point (2): "An earlier-filed application of another, from any country is prior art from earliest effective filing date of claimed invention, provided that the application is subsequently published. 35 U.S.C. §102(a)(2)"

Comment: @user132162 same source: inventor is prior art as of its earliest effective filing date, regardless of whether the earliest application was filed in the English language. Thus, a published U.S. patent application can now be used for both novelty and obviousness determinations against patent applications of other inventors irrespective of whether the priority application was filed in a non-English language.

Comment: Your quote seems to relate to the nationality of the inventor.

Comment: @DonQuiKong What I'm saying is that unpublished foreign applications  retro-actively count as prior art in the US (for both novelty and obviousness purposes), assuming the foreign applications eventually publish.

Comment: @user132162 I don't think so